# NedB on heroku dont keep db file

Tags: node.js, database, heroku, nedb

i used nedb in my nodejs app , first of my code is :

```
var Datastore = require('nedb');
var db = new Datastore({ filename: 'users.db', autoload: true });
db.persistence.setAutocompactionInterval(5);
```

everything is ok with local host , and database will save every thick in my db file . (Database saved after server restarting)
but in heroku server , database is empty !!!
i think database saved as in-memory ! (not in my db file !!) Why ?!
i want keep my database in my db file in Heroku server !

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Heroku dynos have an [ephemeral file system](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/dynos#ephemeral-filesystem), so you shouldn't be trying to save your database there. From the documentation:

> During the dyno’s lifetime its running processes can use the
>   filesystem as a temporary scratchpad, but no files that are written
>   are visible to processes in any other dyno and any files written will
>   be discarded the moment the dyno is stopped or restarted.

You'll have a better time adding a MongoDB addon and writing to that instead.